# Принцип открытости/закрытости и Лисков при использовании WPF и ASP template селекторов

Tags: c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Имеются WPF и ASP MVC приложения, которые показывают информацию о преподавателях и студентах.

WPF приложение отображает информацию о преподавателях и студентах в едином ListBox, при этом для типа StudentViewModel и TeachViewModel написан соответствующий DataTemplate. То же самое происходит в ASP MVC приложении только с использованием DisplayFor хелпера.
И WPF, и ASP приложение запрашивают данные из следующего сервиса:

```
interface IService
{
   IList<AbstractPersonDto> GetAllPersons();
   void SaveAllPersons(IList<AbstractPersonDto> persons);
}
```

Также существуют классы StudentDto и TeacherDto. 
WPF и ASP приложения маппят AbstractPersonDto -> AbstractViewModel, StudentDto -> StudentViewModel и TeacherDto -> TeacherViewModel с помощью AutoMapper. 
Не нарушается ли здесь принцип открытости/закрытости и Барбары Лисков? Ведь происходит так, что если что-то новое унаследуется от AbstractPersonDto, маппер не найдет подходящего соответствия. Т.е. класс, реализующий маппинг открыт для модификаций. Или я не прав?

То же самое при выборе подходяещего DataTemplate в WPF и PartialView в ASP. Получается, что если я унаследую что-то от нашей абстрактной AbstractPersonViewModel, то мне необходимо модифицировать View. Т.е. View, получается, тоже открыт для модификаций?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы заморачиваетесь. Маппинг реализован в AutoMapper. Ваш класс маппера только задает правила конвертации. А их в любом случае придется задать <где-то>, хотя бы в виде аттрибутов. Это не значит что <где-то> - открыто для модификаций.

Необходимось внести где-то модификацию будет в любом случае - пусть даже в виде аттрибутов или в виде кода-конфигурации. Главное чтобы вам не пришлось править сам AutoMapper для этого.

То же самое с принципом Лисков:

> Функции, которые используют базовый тип, должны иметь возможность использовать подтипы базового типа, не зная об этом.

Он сформулирован не как "должны работать со всеми подтипами". А как "должны иметь возможность использовать". Этот принцип не накладывает ограничения на логику *функции маппинга*.

Он накладывает ограничение на логику, содержащуюся в классе `AbstractPersonDto` и его наследниках - вы должны изменять **поведение наследников** `AbstractPersonDto` только так, чтобы **именно эти изменения** не вынуждали код, испольщующий `AbstractPersonDto` проверять тип передаваемого значения.

Т.е. если до изменений тип не проверялся, а после изменений обязательно проверяется - тогда принцип нарушен.

Учитывая что в DTO логики в принципе нет, нарушить наследованием от него принцип подставновки Лисков практически невозможно.